# In the Ozarks, why was a pregnant woman "with squirrel"?

Tags: etymology, phrase-origin, colloquialisms, euphemisms, southern-white-vernacular-english

Many blog posts online claim that in the Ozarks, being 'with squirrel' was once slang for 'being pregnant.' That is, if Sally is 'with squirrel', then Sally is pregnant.

They mostly cite Vance Randolph's 1953 *[Down in the Holler: A Gallery of Ozark Folk Speech](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Down_in_the_Holler/SUWFzgEACAAJ?hl=en)* as their source, though they fail to give the actual quote. It's not easily available online, but [this](https://the-gneech.livejournal.com/1133352.html) dude seems to have posted the relevant entry in the book:

> Pregnancy is seldom mentioned when both men and women are present... If no women are about, a hillman may remark to a comparative stranger that his wife is *ketched*, or ... *too big for her clothes*, or *comin' fresh* ... or ***with squirrel***.

<s>*Ketched* seems to be simply nonsense,</s> (never mind, it's probably not) the next two are somewhat self-explanatory, but the last one looks random enough to be interesting. (It seems that, contrary to modern assertions, it's more euphemistic than it is slangy.)

I'm aware that being *with child* means that one is pregnant, but how would that turn into *with squirrel*? (If it indeed derives from that expression.) The only explanation I can think of for that would be if *baby* was a synonym for *squirrel* in the region, but a (cursory) Google search suggests that this isn't the case.

The one suggested etymology I found was in [The Facts on File Dictionary of American Regionalisms {2000; Robert Hendrickson}](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Facts_on_File_Dictionary_of_American/yXY0yQnvmmUC?hl=en&gbpv=1&pg=PA417&printsec=frontcover), but it's very unconfident and seems to be clutching at straws:

> ... perhaps a woman carrying an active child suggested someone with a squirrel in her belly, but the origin of the term is unknown.

So, is there a better theory? Why did *being with squirrel* mean 'being pregnant'?

Comment: You suggest baby was a synonym for squirrel. I suggest squirrel is a synonym for baby. Closer in logic than *a bun in the oven*.

Comment: I'd think that "ketched", rather than being simply nonsense, was a spelling variant of "catched", but who knows.

Comment: It is worth noting that the word "pregnant" was once considered rather obscene, leading to a profusion of euphemisms.

Comment: The Ozarks are not in the South; they're in the woods. Maybe it has to do with the shapes they make appear when moving around in utero?

Comment: @HippoSawrUs - are you objecting to the use of the [southern-white-vernacular-english] tag? Interesting theory.

Comment: No, no, it's fine. The Census considers that the South (in addition to DC and Maryland). I'm just saying the rural Ozarks kind of have their own thing going on…like a 7 y/o can cook a whole turkey and the best deer ever (even if you hated deer before); it's a whole other place. Whereas in AL, they will serve deep-fried squirrel head to a little kid on a sleepover; regions differ significantly.

Comment: @TimR - I've lived in Alabama and Georgia; they're night and day.

Comment: Being from the largest settlement of Gaelic-speaking Highland Scots in North America, I've never heard that expression, but I'm not that old, relatively speaking.

Answer (score 4):

This is just a guess, but it might be a somewhat jocular use of one meaning of *squirrel*, which is

> **squirrel** *v.t.*
> 5. to store or hide (money, valuables, etc.) for the future, as squirrels store nuts and seeds for winter (often fol. by away).
> <sub>[TFD Online](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/squirrel)</sub>

A pregnant woman is certainly storing something for the future, so that would suggest a connection.

Answer (score 1):

Robert Hendrikson, [*The Facts on File Dictionary of American Regionalisms*](https://books.google.com/books?id=yXY0yQnvmmUC&pg=PA417&dq=%22with+squirrel%22+Ozarks&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjDnJ6f15qCAxW3KEQIHdGyA5gQ6AF6BAgIEAI#v=onepage&q=%22with%20squirrel%22%20Ozarks&f=false) (2000) has this brief entry for "with squirrel":

> **with squirrel** An Ozarkian synonym for pregnant or with child; perhaps a woman carrying an active child suggested someone with a squirrel in her belly, but the origin of the term is unknown.

Although Vance Randolph was undoubtedly an early source of the expression "with squirrel," he doesn't mention it in his early and widely cited "[A Word-List from the Ozarks](https://books.google.com/books?id=lxwOAAAAIAAJ&pg=PA146&lpg=PA146&dq=%22Flapper+Filology%22&source=bl&ots=YkmKYKiVo9&sig=qJDeTgt-yjVOuLF7CKbxqoGM5VE&hl=en&sa=X&ei=Or7WU_qQMu3oigKf_YDwCg&ved=0CCUQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=%22squirrel-turner%22&f=false)" in *Dialect Notes*, volume 5, part 9 (1926).

The earliest print mention of the expression that I've been able to find is from an [unidentified word list](https://books.google.com/books?id=mNo4AAAAMAAJ&q=%22with+squirrel%22+Ozarks&dq=%22with+squirrel%22+Ozarks&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjO39fl2pqCAxWWhu4BHT2wD584FBDoAXoECA0QAg) in *American Speech* (February 1935) [cited text not visible in snippet window]:

> **WITH SQUIRREL,** *adv. phr.* Pregnant.

Harold Wentworth, *American Dialect Dictionary* (1944) notes field-collected occurrences of the expression from the period 1933–1936 in the Ozarks area:

> **with squirrel.** Pregnant. **1933–6 s[outh]w[est] M[issouri]–n[orth]w[est] Ark[ansas].**

One point that may help readers make sense of the adoption of "with squirrel" as a regionalism is that people in the Ozarks region (in the first half of the twentieth century, anyway) were notably prone to euphemisms on sexual topics—especially in mixed company. As Hendrickson points out in his *Dictionary of American Regionalisms*, this diffidence led people in the area to refer to woodpeckers as "woodchucks.":

> **woodchuck** Woodpecker, because of the *pecker* in its name, is a taboo word in the Ozarks, where a woodpecker is euphemistically called a woodchuck.

Similarly, Hendrickson reports, a popular Southern mountains euphemism for "any married woman who accidentally becomes pregnant" was "stumped her toe."

Comment: It's always nice to know the first instance, so thank you, but your first quote was in the question already, and the euphemistic nature of the expression is mentioned in the Randolph excerpt I quoted. Your other examples are interesting, but still don't really get at what I'm asking.